# std::map type signature (declaration) of template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost, associative-array

I have defined a lots of template class variables like this:

```cpp
someTemplate<int, int, char> variable1;
someTemplate<char, int, char> variable2;
someTemplate<double, double, int> variable3;
someTemplate<int, int, char> variable4;
someTemplate<int, int, float> variable15;
...
```

Now, I would like to define associative std::map, but I don't know how to write type signature (declaration)... if it is even possible. For example:

```cpp
std::map<int,_____> assocArr;
```

I need it because I want to call function on all items of std::map using loop:

```cpp
for(auto item : assocArr)
{
    if(item.first == integerVar)
        item.second->myFunction();
}
```

I know, that simple solution is make class, which encapsulate all template classes, but my question is if possible to do it without this class?
Usage of boost::variant is problematic due to many of variants of template class.

Comment: Those are all different types.  you could make a common base class and make that the type in the map.

Comment: Is the idea to store pointers to all your variables in the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the Boost Type Erasure route too.

```
BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((has_myFunction), myFunction, 0)

namespace bte = boost::type_erasure;
using Erased = bte::any<
    boost::mpl::vector<
        bte::copy_constructible<>,
        has_myFunction<void(), bte::_self const>, 
        bte::relaxed 
    > >;
```

This has a bit more of a learning curve¹, but it might be a very good trade-off if you have many more concepts to cater for.

The sample also shows how to achieve value-semantics for the map values (assuming that `someTemplate<>` is copy-constructible).

### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24d3fb3053d14d0a)</kbd>**

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/member.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/constructible.hpp>

BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((has_myFunction), myFunction, 0)

namespace bte = boost::type_erasure;
using Erased = bte::any<
    boost::mpl::vector<
        bte::copy_constructible<>,
        has_myFunction<void(), bte::_self const>, 
        bte::relaxed 
    > >;

template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
struct someTemplate {
    void myFunction() const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<int, Erased> assocArr {
        { 1,  someTemplate<int,    int,    char>  {} },
        { 2,  someTemplate<char,   int,    char>  {} },
        { 3,  someTemplate<double, double, int>   {} },
        { 4,  someTemplate<int,    int,    char>  {} },
        { 5,  someTemplate<int,    int,    float> {} },
    };

    for(auto& item : assocArr)
        //if(item.first == integerVar)
    {
        std::cout << "id: " << item.first << " ";
        item.second.myFunction();
    }
}
```

Printing:

```
id: 1 void someTemplate<T, U, V>::myFunction() const [with T = int; U = int; V = char]
id: 2 void someTemplate<T, U, V>::myFunction() const [with T = char; U = int; V = char]
id: 3 void someTemplate<T, U, V>::myFunction() const [with T = double; U = double; V = int]
id: 4 void someTemplate<T, U, V>::myFunction() const [with T = int; U = int; V = char]
id: 5 void someTemplate<T, U, V>::myFunction() const [with T = int; U = int; V = float]
```

¹ as the live stream does prove :)

Comment: Aaaaand see me struggling with Boost Type Erasure on [the second part of the live-stream](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/boost-type-erasure-for-map-values/) ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost Type Erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33018656/85371) or make your own custom type erasure wrapper.

Yes this means storing a wrapper, but that's what you need. Because maps can not contain "any random type", and using e.g. `boost::any` won't work well if there are *"many of variants of template class"*.

Rough sketch: WIP https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7925ab73ebd7b51f)</kbd>**

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
struct someTemplate {
    void myFunction() const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
};

struct someErasure {
    template <typename... Ts> /*explicit*/ someErasure(someTemplate<Ts...> const& v) 
        : _holder(new holder<someTemplate<Ts...> >(&v))
    { }

    someErasure(someErasure const& rhs) : _holder(rhs._holder->clone()) { }

    void myFunction() const {
        _holder->myFunction();
    }

  private:
    struct itf {
        virtual void myFunction() const = 0;
        virtual itf* clone() const = 0;
    };

    template <typename T> struct holder : itf {
        holder(T const* v) : _v(v) { }
        T const* _v;

        virtual void myFunction() const {
            _v->myFunction();
        }

        virtual holder* clone() const { return new holder(_v); }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<itf> _holder;
};

int main() {
    someTemplate<int,    int,    char>  variable1;
    someTemplate<char,   int,    char>  variable2;
    someTemplate<double, double, int>   variable3;
    someTemplate<int,    int,    char>  variable4;
    someTemplate<int,    int,    float> variable5;

    std::map<int, someErasure> assocArr {
        { 1,  variable1 },
        { 2,  variable2 },
        { 3, variable3 },
        { 4,  variable4 },
        { 5,  variable5 },
    };

    for(auto& item : assocArr)
        //if(item.first == integerVar)
    {
        std::cout << "id: " << item.first << " ";
        item.second.myFunction();
    }
}
```

Printing

```
id: 1 void someTemplate<T, U, V>::myFunction() const [with T = int; U = int; V = char]
id: 2 void someTemplate<T, U, V>::myFunction() const [with T = char; U = int; V = char]
id: 3 void someTemplate<T, U, V>::myFunction() const [with T = double; U = double; V = int]
id: 4 void someTemplate<T, U, V>::myFunction() const [with T = int; U = int; V = char]
id: 5 void someTemplate<T, U, V>::myFunction() const [with T = int; U = int; V = float]
```

Comment: Posted a an example of [Ad-hoc type-erasure for `std::map` values](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/ad-hoc-type-erasure-for-stdmap-values/)